# popup-menuの関数名の最後のアスタリスクについて

Tags: emacs, elisp

`popup.el`を使いたくて`cask`でインストールして、まずポップアップ表示ができるかまで確認して、次にヘルパー関数の`popup-menu`を使った表示を試したく Github の解説にある

```
(popup-menu* '("Foo" "Bar" "Baz"))
```

を試してみた所

```
setq: Wrong type argument: wholenump, -253
```

のエラーになってしまいました。そこで

```
(popup-menu '("Foo" "Bar" "Baz"))
```

と`*`を抜いてみたら表示されました。

その後`(setq popup (popup-create (point) 10 10))`を宣言したりしてると何故か`*`付きのものもポップアップが表示されたりされなかったりするのですが、具体的にどの`elisp`を読み込んだら表示されるかの条件はわかりませんでした。

まずわからない所を一つずつ潰していきたいので`*`の有無による動作の違いをわかる方いませんでしょうか？